# Create a space with Google Chat REST API

Tags: google-hangouts, google-chat

We have a program that uses a service account to manage various thing inside Google Chat.

Now, we have the need to create a new space using the Google Chat REST API (spaces.create).
We already joined the developer preview program, as this endpoint is not yet generally available.

From what we understand, this endpoint is not possible to invoke via service account and so we wanted to ask you… can we invoke this endpoint automatically using “domain delegation”? If yes, how?

We always want to use the service account as it is not possible to show a login prompt to the user.

We enabled the domain delegation but that endpoint returns always status 403. (We are using Google.Apis library for .NET Core

```cs
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("key.json")
    .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces.create")
    .CreateWithUser("service-account-email@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com");

var token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces");
request.Headers.Authorization = new("Bearer", token);

var payload = @"
{
    ""name"": ""testspace-1"",
    ""spaceType"": ""SPACE"",
    ""singleUserBotDm"": true,
    ""displayName"": ""Test Space""
}
";

request.Content = new StringContent(payload, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient client = new();

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Sorry but we don't need help with the core itself. We just wanted to know if is it possible to use domain delegation (on a service account) for creating a new space

Comment: Can i get a full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation [Auth](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth)

You will notice it stats that service account authorization is supported.  If you are part of the[developer preview program](https://developers.google.com/workspace/preview)

[image]

The reason I asked about your code is that the last time i tried this which notably was a while ago.  The google .net client library was not generated the methods that were under preview.

So while it may work yes. The issue your may have is that the client library when loaded will not have the method you need meaning you will have to code the call to the endpoint yourself.

If this is in fact the case let me know if you have any issues peceing it together I may be able to help.

## update your code

There is an error in your code

```
 .CreateWithUser("service-account-email@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
```

The email in `CreateWithUser` should be the user on your domain who you wish to delicate the service account as. Not the service account email address.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've added the code snippet

Comment: @linda-lawton-daimto
I'm part of the "Google Workspace Developper Preview Program and have access to the preview "libraries". But I'm unable to find any place where they explain how to use those libraries (I'm using js). Could you provide guidance on how to use them and how to create spaces with a SA, please? Thanks in advance